# Mapping navigation property in abstract base class with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have different Cars and each has a specific car type. 
All cars inherit from same abstract base class CarBase. The CarBase class has a navigaiton property to CarType.

```
public abstract CarTypeBase 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FordCarType : CarTypeBase 
{

}

public abstract class CarBase {
     public CarTypeBase CarType { get; set; }

     public string GetName() {
           return CarType.Name;
     }      
}

public class Ford : CarBase {

}
```

The Ford is mapped with the following EF mapping configuration:

```
builder.HasOne(o => (FordCarType) o.CarType);
```

For the CarTypeBase class I'm using the default Table per Hierarchy (TPH) mapping of Entity Framework, so the CarTypeBase table has a discriminator column.
And the Ford table has a Foreign Key to CarTypeBase table.

The problem is that the Ford CarType navigation property is always null if I'm trying to access it for instance in the GetName() method. If I use instead the concrete type FordCarType the CarType property will be mapped in the Ford class.

So maybe what I want to achieve is not possible with EF or isn't possible at all?

Comment: "The problem is that the Ford CarType navigation property is always null" Please add the code that gets you this

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the GetName() method to the CarBase class. Trying to access the Name property of CarTypeBase is not possbile, because CarType is null.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. I mean, add the code to how you get the instance (how you load it from the database)

Comment: I'm getting my cars from the ApplicationDbContext, like context.Cars. But I realised, I haven't specified to include the CarType and as far as I know lazy loading is not supported in EF Core yet. So this could be the issue. But when I include the CarType like context.Cars.Include(o => o.CarType) I get an ArgumentException "Argument types do not match".

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but, shouldn't this be:

```
public abstract CarTypeBase 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CarBase : CarTypeBase  {
        
     public string GetName() {
           return this.Name;
     }      
}

public class Ford : CarBase {

}
```